# Can I run a Linux shell script in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, git-bash

I created Shell Script on Linux and it runs fine.

Now I want to run the same script on Windows using `gitbash`. (Only filepath changed for windows)

I am confused:

- do I need to write a new shell script again according to Windows syntax shell script?

or

- can a Linux syntax shell script run on Windows without changes?

According TO [differences-between-windows-batch-and-linux-bash-shell-script-syntax](http://www.xoogu.com/2012/differences-between-windows-batch-and-linux-bash-shell-script-syntax/)

Comment: You can run `bash` on windows, as well as some other UNIX shells (`ash`, `tcsh`) ... However, there are many minor problems you may encounter, as Windows & UNIX are very different ... If you want to make something cross-platform, I advise using Python, Java, Ruby, or some other language better suited for this job.

Comment: if you wrote a Shell script, you can run it in Windows using `cygwin`.

Comment: Here download [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: @fedorqui in my learning 'cygwin' And 'gitbash' do same stuff for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can use Git Bash

It depends on how advanced the scripts are, but simple scripts can be executed in Git Bash.

test.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World!
```

Execute script:

```
./test.sh
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

---

### Git Bash vs Cygwin

To answer your question:

> @fedorqui in my learning 'cygwin' And 'gitbash' do same stuff for
>   windows

**Git Bash**

Git Bash is lightweight and only aims to handle:

- version control
- a shell that runs commands

Read more: http://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash

**Cygwin**

- a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide
  functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.
- a DLL (cygwin1.dll) which provides substantial POSIX API
  functionality.

Read more: https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: thanks for teaching **Cygwin** for Complex scripts is more better than **gitbash** for simple scripts.As Cygwin brings bigger part of linux environment in windows.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. There is a tool called [`cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/) that allows you to do so.

Note that you have to check what the paths are. If so, go to the path you are willing to work on and do `pwd`. This way, you will get the `Windows\kind\of\path`.

I use it all the time and it works pretty fine.

Comment: Awesome! Changing **slash** for windows environment got my script working And Used **cygwin**